# jQuery how to select children first level div's

Tags: jquery, css, target

I have a little bit problem with targeting some div's without class, situated in table structure:

```
<table class="blog" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <div>               <--- I want to target this
          <table class="some_table_class">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="someclass" valign="top">
                   <div>This div should stay untouched, and every of his potential div children</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div></div>      <--- I want to target this
        <div></div>      <--- I want to target this
        <div></div>      <--- I want to target this
         .
         .
         .
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to do it just in CSS `.blog td[valign="top"]>div` but this one is effecting second div too + seems like IE don't understand what [valign="top"] is

so I want to add some class to those divs with jQuery

is there any effective way how to do that?

`.blog>tbody>tr>td>div` ... is a bit weird and long to use, I think

thank you for any ideas

I forgot .. *I am able to edit html structure just with jquery, I don't have access to .php / .html files*

Comment: Assign classes or ID`s to your divs and you can address them easily with $("#mydivID") or $(".mydivClass")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $('td[valign="top"]').find("div") // this will find all the divs
```

**updated**

either you name all the divs, with a class selector and get that with class selector..

or else you can use `not()` to exclude that.. but need to give an id or class that should be excluded...

**HTML**

```
<div id="notthis">This div should stay untouched, and every
```

**Jquery**

```
$('td[valign="top"]').find("div:not('#notthis')").addClass('test');
```

simple example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Myykv/)

**updated after comment**

```
$('td[valign="top"]').find("div:not('.someclass div')").addClass('test')
```

Comment: It also does affect `<td class="someclass" valign="top"> <div>` I think

I want to target just those div's in first level table

Comment: The selector matches both the first level and the nested <code>td</code> => your first line will return the UNWANTED div twice whereas the 2nd will return it once.

Comment: u should add a class to those global td

Comment: that looks fine, ... 
I found that `$('td[valign="top"]').find("div:not('.someclass div')").addClass('test');` work as well, and maybe a bit better solution, in case that #notthis will contain some other div's. Thank you very much :)

Comment: yes.. you got it... :).. damn!! i missed that.. anyways.. glad it helped .... i will update by answer likewise.. thanks.. :)..happy coding

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should more rely on classes that you set yourself , instead of html attributes.

If you are sure about your markup, try `$('table.blog>tbody>tr>td>div')` .
However, If I were you, I'd add a class onto ot closer to the target item i order to write a simpler selector.. that'd make it more flexible to maintain.

Comment: yes, that's why I want to target those divs to add them some classes

I am not abel to do it in .php files :/

Comment: OK, _if you cannot modify the initial markup_, I understand it as an meaningful practice to have a little bit of client side processing  to do enhance it.. then build more stable code based on the enhanced markup.